# VFP function to check if a method is defined

Tags: function, methods, visual-foxpro

I would like to trigger a method of an object by using `BINDEVENT()`, but the method may not exist. Thus, I want to check if the method is defined before issuing `BINDEVENT()`.

For example, in the following code snippet, if `oHandler.myresize()` does not exist, the error will be triggered at the line of `BINDEVENT()`.

```
PUBLIC oHandler
oHandler=NEWOBJECT("myhandler")
DO (_browser)
BINDEVENT(_SCREEN,"Resize",oHandler,"myresize")

DEFINE CLASS myhandler AS Session
   PROCEDURE myresize
      IF ISNULL(_obrowser) THEN
         UNBINDEVENTS(THIS)
      ELSE
         _obrowser.left = _SCREEN.Width - _obrowser.width
      ENDIF
   RETURN
ENDDEFINE
```

Thus, I want to check the method `myresize()` exists or not.
Is there any language function for this purpose? It is very similar to a php function [function_exits()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) or [method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEMSTATUS( VariableNameRepresentingTheObject, "MethodOrPropertyLookingFor", 5 )

returns true or false if exists on the given object.

Comment: Ah..I used it before, but forgot. Thanks!